# .RData objects seem to disappear, affecting my cron jobs

Tags: r, rdata

I have a cron job running an R script that checks the values of certain variables and sends an email depending on said values (with an if-statement), then it will alter the value, the cronjob runs every 5 minutes indefinitely, however the cron will only work after the first instance of the if-statement being satisfied. After that it seems the objects disappear from the workspace and therefore causes the script to fail:

```
load("/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData") # the objects load successfully the first time

print("CURTAILING $200:")
print(curtailing_200) # this is where the fail occurs, it says the object cannot be found after the first entrance into the if-statement, as per my cron logs
print("LAST DECISION $200:")
print(last_decision_200)
print("SMP LENGTH $200:")
length(smp_vec)
print("SMP VEC $200:")
mean(smp_vec)



if ((length(smp_vec) == 31) && (mean(smp_vec) > 200) && (curtailing_200 == FALSE) && (now >= last_decision_200 )) { #send curtailment notice if we are in the 30th minute and conditions are met
  print("IF")
  curtailment_start_200()
  curtailing_200 = TRUE # here I reassign a new value
  last_decision_200 = now # here I assign a new value
  save(curtailing_200, file="/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData") 
  save(last_decision_200, file="/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData")
  save.image() # save the values
}
```

Sorry if this sounds confusing, but basically the objects are loaded fine, until the if-statement gets satisfied eventually, then inside the if-statement I alter the objects and save them (seemingly). Then after that it seems the objects are gone.

Comment: Well, you save `curtaling_200` in a file named `.RData`. Then immediately that's pointless because you overwrite that file with a new `.RData` file containing only `last_decision_200`. Then you save your whole workspace in a file named `.RData` in the current working directory which - based on your error - probably isn't `"/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/
"`.

Comment: So I would suggest deleting the 2 `save()` lines, and edit the `save.image` like to specify the full file path, `save.image(file ="/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData")`. `save` and `save.image` don't append R objects to an RData file, they overwrite the whole file. But since `save.image` saves everything, you don't need to save the first two objects separately. You just need to make sure `save.image` puts its file in the right place.

Comment: Ohh I had a feeling something like that was happening! that makes sense thank you. I assumed `save()` just saved the specified object. If you post the answer I'd gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save()` saves one or more objects in a file, but it cannot update an existing file. `save.image()` writes all your objects to a file, but since you are not specifying its location my guess is it ends up in the wrong place.

```
  save(curtailing_200, file="/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData")
  ## saves one object


  save(last_decision_200, file="/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData") 
  ## overwrites the previous object with this one


  save.image() 
  ## if this goes to the same place, it will overwrite the previous line
  ## but since R can't find the objects after load()
  ## it probably is going to the wrong folder
```

Replace those 3 lines above with

```
save.image(file = "/home/ec2-user/R_Scripts/.RData")
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Cron DOES NOT look for .RData in the same directory as your project. The same way Rscripts does when you run it manually. So specifying the directory was necessary. Word of warning to anyone else here